# How to increase wait timer precision to 1ms in UWP?

Tags: timer, uwp, scheduling

It is important for my usecase to have functions like Sleep and WaitForMultipleObjects w/timeout to have 1ms resolution on the timeout.

In normal Windows apps, it's possible to achieve this by calling timeBeginPeriod(1). Unfortunately, UWP does not seem to provide this function.

I can see the timer resolution increases affecting the UWP app - that is, if I run Chrome while the UWP app is running, the timer resolution in UWP app increases to 1ms; when I close Chrome it goes back to what looks like 15ms.

Is there a way to achieve the same from within a UWP app using some API other than timeBeginPeriod?

Comment: What do you need the extra precision for? One of the reasons this isn't available to UWP is because it's a global setting that lowers battery life & performance for the whole machine (from [the MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757624(v=vs.85).aspx)). Is the Centennial Desktop Bridge an option for you?

Comment: The app in question is a real-time game and the scheduling mechanisms it uses for the internal job system are sensitive to timer precision. Battery life thus is not a significant concern (especially since some apps like Chrome lower it for the entire system anyway).

Comment: As for desktop bridge, I'm not really sure - we are already distributing the app in question so we can't completely retrofit it to use that; does desktop bridge allow to use some desktop APIs from an app that otherwise is built on UWP "natively"?

Comment: You can add a desktop fullTrust component that simply calls that API for you. You need to [get approval from Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge) to ship in the Store.

Comment: I would also like to know if there's an answer to this - my Win32 app can give me millisecond timer resolution, but the function is missing in UWP and Desktop Bridge is not available on XBox.